# Selecting all resources but want a column of CSVs that is calculated on a per row basis

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Problem Statement**

I would like to select all of the resources that belong to a certain company, for each resource I would like to get a comma separated list of the groups that it belongs to (using `string_agg`).

**DB Relationships**

```
Resources
=============================
ResourceId (PK)
CompanyId (FKs to Company)
ResourceName
...
Other columns that are not important

Company
=============================
CompanyId (PK)
...
Other columns that are not important

GroupResources
=============================
GroupId (PK and FKs to Group)
ResourceId (PK and FKs to Resources)

Group
=============================
GroupId (PK)
CompanyId (FKs to Company)
GroupName
...
Other columns that are not important
```

**What I currently have**

I currently have two separate queries, Query A which retrieves all of the information I require except for the aggregate of the groups for each resource, and Query B which retrieves only the aggregate of the groups for each resource in the company.

*Query A*

```
SELECT resources.resourcename, ... other columns that I am selecting out
FROM resources
...
JOINs to tables to get date for some of the other columns
...
WHERE resources.companyid = 1234
ORDER BY resourcename ASC;
```

*Query B*

```
SELECT string_agg(groupname, ',') AS groups
FROM group
JOIN groupresources USING (groupid)
JOIN resources USING (resourceid)
WHERE resources.companyid = 1234
GROUP BY (resourcename)
ORDER BY groups ASC;
```

I know about using subqueries but in this case I'm not quite sure about how to apply that knowledge because it seems like I am trying to perform what would be a two part operation (in languages such as `C#`) in a single hit:

- Get all of the resources for a company
- Populate the groups property for each resource

<strike>Simply adding the `string_agg` statement to Query A will return an aggregated string for all groups in the company, NOT just the ones the resource is part of.</strike> This was an incorrect assumption that I was making, see answer for more details.

**Desired Output**

```
resource1, 'group1,group 2', ...other columns
resource2, 'group3', ...other columns
resource3, 'group1, group3', ...other columns
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption that adding `string_agg` to Query A would return a comma separated list of values for all of the groups in a company, rather than just the groups that the resource in the row belonged to was in correct.

In actual fact adding `string_agg` to Query A forced the use of the `GROUP BY` command because I had other columns that I was selecting outside of the aggregrate function (*...column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function...*). Once I added the relevant columns (everything except the aggregated column) to the `GROUP BY` clause, my query functioned as expected.

**Penultimate Query**

```
SELECT 
    resources.resourcename, 
    ... other columns that I am selecting out...
    string_agg(groupname, ', ') AS Groups
FROM resources
...
JOINs to tables to get data for some of the other columns
LEFT JOIN groupresources USING (resourceid)
LEFT JOIN group USING (groupid)
LEFT JOIN resources USING (resourceid)
...
WHERE resources.companyid = 1234
GROUP BY 
    resourcename, 
    ...all other columns except the one inside the string_agg function...
ORDER BY resourcename ASC;
```

The `GROUP BY` ensured that I was getting results for the groups a resource belonged to, rather than all groups within a company.

***...however this was still excluding some rows as I knew the expected number of resources, and my result was less than this.***

I discovered that I could achieve a similar effect using a `SELECT` inside a `JOIN`.

**Final Query**

```
SELECT 
    resources.resourcename, 
    ... other columns that I am selecting out...
    Groups
FROM resources
...
JOINs to tables to get data for some of the other columns
LEFT JOIN resources USING (resourceid)
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        resourceid, 
        string_agg(groupname,', ' ORDER BY groupname) AS Groups 
    FROM tgroupresources
    JOIN tgroup USING (groupid) 
    GROUP BY resourceid
) AS g USING (resourceid)
...
WHERE resources.companyid = 1234
ORDER BY resourcename ASC;
```

Which returned the full result set.